# .load() loads after scripts / in-page scripts do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Brief

Imagine your first website vastly growing in the amount of code, however particular parts you want to globally modify such as a menu seen on every page. So I've taken my header and added it to it's own file and load it using:

```
// Load Header
$(".Header").load("assets/HTML/header.html");
```

So I've got my header, added it to it's own place to allow a bit of CMS to my website.

### What Makes It Tick?

**Dependant Files:**

- jquery-1.11.0.min.js
- jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
- jquery.ui.widget.js
- jquery.ui.selectmenu.js
- In page script for drop downs and whatnot

### The Problem

The header is loading presumably after all my scripts have loaded regardless of the several places I've tried and tested adding to fetch the header code.

I'm HOPING this is enough to insight some help, some possible problems many encounter as posting my link, it is massively subject to change! Please specify how I could make this question anymore local to Stackoverflow, however for now my [live version can be found here](http://rafflebananza.com/RaffleBananza/Desktop/index.php).

Comment: You could include your header with php includes instead of js, that way the header will be there in the originated html http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php . If you want to use jQuery, you could hide your page until the header is loaded and then show the whole thing. I think the php thing is the way to go.

Comment: By all means, PHP is a very good idea, yet I am not very much experienced yet in PHP @JonasGrumann so let me look over your suggested link

Comment: Okay, I see how to call the page to be included however to continue then to echo this into a specific location on my page I have yet to understand.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've been busy. Here's an article that explains better how to do it http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page it's just a matter of <?php include("includes/header.html");?> no need for the echo stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is good implementation of jQuerys `load()` method.

Have you tried using this pattern instead of using jquerys `.ready()`?

```
$(window).load(function(){
  # your code
  $(".Header").html(yourContent);
});
```

From [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

"Code included inside `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready."

Just remember to put this statement outside of `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Comment: Let me give this a run through as now I'm considering using PHP as suggested by @JonasGrumann, if all is good I'll accept and close this question as I've aimed it at JQuery/JS devs...

Comment: Looking at your code before adding it, would I not need to load the header from the external file then run all the scripts? As my header shows without any JS working...

Comment: Ofc, I use this approach when I need to wait for images to load and then do something.

Comment: @TimMarshall Well it really depends. You can ie embed header html in js and call it everywhere from there or you can use Ajax or maybe some other tehique.

Comment: So I added your suggestion... Probably wrong! - It's not working... I added your code above all my other code and then wrapped my other code in the doc read function.

Comment: Yeah, you can't paste this code, you have to modify it first. Btw, reading comment I saw Jonas suggestion, you should definitely use phps `include()`. Its a lot easier. That should be your answer.

Comment: I did not literally copy your code, I did modify it. You can check the updated live view if you wish? In regards to PHP, I could only see how to include my file to the page, not echo this in a specific region. If you would not mind showing a little more on how to do this via PHP that would be brilliant!

Comment: First things first, you use jeuqrys `load()` in the wrong manner, its only callback for when DOM is fully loaded with all the resources. What you probably need is Ajax call that should load content. Second, yes you can include your header where ever you wish with `include()`. Why do you need it to echo? I'm no php expert but I included my headers and fotters this way: `<?php include 'file_name.php';?>` and they rendered correctly.

Comment: Oh jeeze! You simply add `<?php include 'assets/HTML/header.html';?>`?!!! I thought this included ready to implement somewhere... All working! =D

Comment: Glad we help, it was all Jonas actually, I didn't notice that it was built on php, next time put a tag :)